# Start debugging with Visual Studio from a different folder

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Visual Studio solution with set *After-build* commands. Those commands copy all files from the *bin/Debug* folder to the *SOLUTION/Build/Debug* folder.

Now I am trying to run debug from that *SOLUTION/Build/Debug* folder. Is that possible?

I have found in the *Settings* -> *Debug* -> *Start External* ... option, but this option won't accept a relative path to the executable (we need it relative as multiple developers are working on the project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way how to do this.

First is needed to set in project properties *Debug > Start External* and *Debug > Working directory* to absolute paths. Then edit manually project file *project.csproj.user* and update it like this:

```
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>$(SolutionDir)Build\Debug\Prototype.exe</StartProgram>
<StartWorkingDirectory>$(SolutionDir)Build\Debug\</StartWorkingDirectory>
```

Then it is working as is needed.